# MySQL select join where AND where

Tags: mysql, join, where-in, relational-division

I have two tables in my database:

**Products**

- id (int, primary key)
- name (varchar)

**ProductTags**

- product_id (int)
- tag_id (int)

I would like to select products having all given tags. I tried:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Products
JOIN ProductTags ON Products.id = ProductTags.product_id
WHERE
    ProductTags.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
    Products.id
```

But it gives me products having any of given tags, instead of having all given tags. Writing `WHERE tag_id = 1 AND tag_id = 2` is pointless, because no rows will be returned.

Comment: I dont understand what you are after? Do you care to elaborate with some data and examples?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This type of problem is known as [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

```
SELECT Products.* 
FROM Products
JOIN ProductTags ON Products.id = ProductTags.product_id
WHERE ProductTags.tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY Products.id /*<--This is OK in MySQL other RDBMSs 
                          would want the whole SELECT list*/

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductTags.tag_id) = 3 /*Assuming that there is a unique
                                              constraint on product_id,tag_id you 
                                              don't need the DISTINCT*/
```

Comment: This solves the problem. I wonder what number 3 stands for in the last line. I'm getting correct results with: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductTags.tag_id) = 1` and any size of tags id array: `WHERE ProductTags.tag_id IN (1,2,3,4)`

Comment: You would need to adjust the `3` as appropriate. For `(1,2,3,4)` you would need to use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductTags.tag_id) = 4` otherwise you would be bringing back those that had any 3 matching tags out of the 4.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a group by / count to ensure all are accounted for

```
select Products.*
  from Products 
         join ( SELECT Product_ID
                  FROM ProductTags
                  where ProductTags.tag_id IN (1,2,3)
                  GROUP BY Products.id
                  having count( distinct tag_id ) = 3 ) PreQuery
        on ON Products.id = PreQuery.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `WHERE fieldname IN (1,2,3)` is essentially shorthand for `WHERE fieldname = 1 OR fieldname = 2 OR fieldname = 3`.  So if you aren't getting the desired functionality with `WHERE ... IN` then try switching to `OR`s.  If that still doesn't give you the results you want, then perhaps `WHERE ... IN` is not the function you need to use.