# SQL AND and OR in 1-N mapping table

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL select join where AND where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017680/mysql-select-join-where-and-where)

Well, I have a table -

```
 id  map_id     
 -----------
 100   1
 100   2
 101   1
 101   2
 101   3
 102   3
```

Now, I need to do an AND and OR operation on this data. That is,

OR - I have to get the id of all the rows with map_id 1 or 3. So, if I look for 1 or 3 the query should return

> ```
>    100
>    102
> ```

I can do this simply by

> Select id from table where map_id IN (1,3)

AND - If I query for 1 and 2, then I want the ids 100 and 101. And, this I am not able to find a query for.

I initially thought a simple query like this should work but I was wrong.

> Select id from table where map_id = 1 AND map_id = 2  [Doesn't work]

I want to get a result like this but my query doesn't give me this. I don't want to resort to sub queries or joins, well, unless I really don't have to. I tried grouping by ids and using different having clauses but I found a solution yet.

> ```
>    100
>    101
> ```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM   table WHERE  map_id IN (1,2) GROUP  BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT map_id) = 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select id 
from yourtable
where map_id IN (1,2)
group by id
having COUNT(distinct map_id)=2 -- where this 2 is the number of items you want to find
```

This technique is called relational division.

Comment: `having COUNT(*)=2` will do if a unique constraint was set on `map_id` for every `ID`, anyway `+1`.